# vbs : como esperar pelo fim da execução de cópia

Tags: windows-10, vbs, vbscript

No programa seguinte em `VBScript` tento fazer a cópia de um grupo de ficheiros (em `fileCollection`) para um ficheiro zip já criado:

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")'Reference the Text directory
Set SAPP = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set StdOut = FSO.GetStandardStream (1)
...
zipFile = FSO.GetAbsolutePathName(zipFile)

For Each file in fileCollection
  StdOut.WriteLine("- " & FSO.GetAbsolutePathName(file))
  SAPP.NameSpace(zipFile).CopyHere(FSO.GetAbsolutePathName(file))
Next
```

No entanto, este script completa-se antes de todos os ficheiros estarem no zip file... Mesmo com `WScript.Sleep(15*1000)` o script não completa a execução (tenho 23 ficheiros e 750 K para comprimir)...

As minhas questões são:

Como esperar que a cópia esteja completa antes de terminar o script?

Sempre que corro este script, uma grande quantidade de janelas de diálogo abre-se, dizendo qualquer coisa como 'Ficheiro não localizado ou sem permissão de leitura'...

Pode esta cópia demorar mesmo muito tempo?